# How to swap tonkens in pancakeSwap using nodeJS

Tags: ethers.js, nodejs, pancakeswap, swaps

I need to write a script to swap tokens in PancakeSwap using NodeJS. I'm new to web3 development, so maybe I'm misunderstanding some of what I'm seeing in the various docs.

I know PancakeSwap doesn't have an API to do this (swap tokens).

I found that I have to use ethers.js and V3SwapRouter to do the swap operation. But I don't understand how to combine them.
V3SwapRouter: https://docs.pancakeswap.finance/developers/smart-contracts/pancakeswap-exchange/v3-contracts/smartrouterv3/v3swaprouter

Maybe someone can share an example of such a script?

P.S. I will also be very grateful if you recommend courses for beginners in web3.

Comment: Check out udemy. They have some web3 courses. Check back frequently have sales that are very inexpensive.